# Can we use current views exposed filter values to prepopulate another form?

Tags: 7, views, users

I've set up a view that displays users and has exposed filters user first and last names. If there is no user matching the filter values, I'd like to display a link to create a new user and prepopulate the name fields with the values searched in views.

I know there's the prepopulate module and likely other methods to do the actual prepopulating, but I guess this question is more centered on how to grab the filter values so they can be added to the new link url as properly formatted arguments.

EDIT: Got this solved with help from the answer below. Ending up grabbing the filter values with the "exposed filter values" module and populating the field values in a custom module with this code:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {

        //Prepopulate the name fields with url args
        $field_lang = $form['field_name']['#language'];
        if(isset($_GET['first'])) {
            $first = $_GET['first'];
            $form['field_name'][$field_lang][0]['#default_value']['given'] = $first;
        }

        if(isset($_GET['last'])) {
            $last = $_GET['last'];
            $form['field_name'][$field_lang][0]['#default_value']['family']= $last;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling this question some, I came up with the following receipe:

1. Install [prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) and [exposed filter data](https://www.drupal.org/project/exposed_filter_data)
2. Modify exposed_filter_data.tpl.php provided by [exposed filter data](https://www.drupal.org/project/exposed_filter_data) to produce a dynamic prepopulate URL for creating a new user

Hope this helps!

P.S.: Inspired from this discussion => https://www.drupal.org/node/1630198

Comment: Exposed filter data is exactly what I was looking for. Ended up skipping the prepopulate module and implementing some code into a hook_form_alter I already have implemented. Threw that code in as an edit to my question above. Thanks!

Comment: Cool idea, much leaner!

Comment: I haven't had ton of experience so far optimizing security-specific concerns, but do you know if there's anything I should implement to the added code to address injection of any sort? I'd imagine the risk would be mitigated since it's just throwing values into a field, which is handled/validated on form submission anyway.

Comment: Not an expert myself, but I don't think this is the point where you address injection, rather on the output. And I agree, the form submission and subsequent database queries are expected to handle injection concerns.

Comment: Sure! Any time!